# Is it possible to use the Wordpress API (query_posts, WP_Query, get_posts etc) to fetch future posts based on a custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to fetch posts in wordpress that are slated for future publication based on a custom taxonomy query. Finding future posts is 
otherwise, simple

```
query_posts('post_status=future');
```

But adding a custom taxonomy doesn't work as expected

```
query_posts('musicians=paul-mccartney&post_status=future');
```

I ended up using the $wpdb and writing the SQL by hand and joining the terms, taxonomy and relationships tables together.

```
$sql = "SELECT post.* 
  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms term 
  JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy taxonomy
  JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships relationship
  JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts post
  WHERE term.term_id = taxonomy.term_id
  AND relationship.term_taxonomy_id = taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
  AND term.slug = '%s'
  AND taxonomy.taxonomy = '%s'
  AND post.ID = relationship.object_id";

if($posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($sql, $term->slug, $term->taxonomy) )):      
  foreach($posts as $post):
   setup_postdata($post);
     the_ID().' '.the_title().'\n<br/>';
  endforeach;
endif;
```

This works but I'm hoping that there is a way to accomplish the same but using the WP API (query_posts, WP_Query, get_posts etc)!

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Works fine for me - what arguments are you passing to `register_taxonomy`?

Comment: register_taxonomy( 'happenings', 'post', 
    array( 
      'hierarchical' => false, 
      'label' => 'Event location, price and type...', 
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => false
    )
  );

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

```
$events = get_posts('numberposts=-1&post_type=events&musicians=paul-mccartney&post_status=future&order=ASC');
foreach($events as $event){
    setup_postdata($event);
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($event->ID).'">'.$event->post_title.'</a>';
}
```

You can use the same parameters as in,
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters